# Access Selected Date from dynamically created Calendar Control asp/javascript/VB.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, calendar

**UPDATE: To anyone who still may read this, I used a completely different way of doing this. With AjaxToolkit's Calendar Extender, I was able to easily add a calendar dynamically and use Javascript to change the format of different date inputs so that calendar extender could read it. Highly recommend you go the AjaxToolkit route if you are trying to do something similar to me.**

I have dynamically created a Calendar control(asp:Calendar), Buttons, and dropdown lists for a Comment Class. The Comment Class will always have a textbox in it, but if the ID/attribute label of the textbox is DOB or birthday or something similar, these other controls get dynamically created.

So far, the calendar, dropdown lists, and one of the buttons works, but I am have trouble with the last button. Currently, I dynamically add a script that is used for one of the buttons to show and hide the div that contains that Calendar, dropdown lists, and relevant buttons, which works amazingly. I am trying to add another script trigger on a button press to take the selected date from the Calendar and put it in the textbox.

Right now, I am just trying to get access to the Calendar. I am using code that looks like this:

```
function use_calendarDate(){
    var calendarDate = '<%=question128_Cal1.SelectedDate%>';
    alert(calendarDate);
}
```

I found this function in another question similar to this, but instead of getting the date, it just puts <%=question128_Cal1.SelectedDate%> as a string into the alert box.

This [LINK](http://www.aspdotnet-pools.com/2014/12/display-calendar-control-selected-date.html) shows exactly what I am trying to do, but I get a different result. Can anyone help me with what I am doing wrong here?

Interestingly, when I use

```
var calendarDate = question128_Cal1.SelectedDate;
```

OR

```
var calendarDate = question128_Cal1.value;
```

My alert box tells me undefined.

Thanks in advance.

In case it is needed, my calendar control is created like this:

In Page_Init

```
Dim calendar1 As New Calendar
Call BuildCalendar(calendar1)
calendarDiv.Controls.Add(calendar1)
```

Here is the function referenced above.

```
Private Sub BuildCalendar(ByRef calendar1 As Calendar)

    calendar1.ID = "Cal1"
    calendar1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today
    calendar1.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")
    calendar1.Attributes.Add("OnClientDateChanged", "onDateChange")
    calendar1.Attributes.Add("borderwidth", "2px")
    calendar1.Attributes.Add("BackColor", "White")
    calendar1.Attributes.Add("width", "200px")
    calendar1.Attributes.Add("ForeColor", "Black")
    calendar1.Attributes.Add("Height", "180px")
    calendar1.Attributes.Add("Font-Size", "8pt")
    calendar1.Attributes.Add("Font-Names", "Verdana")
    calendar1.Attributes.Add("BorderColor", "#999999")
    calendar1.Attributes.Add("BorderStyle", "Outset")
    calendar1.Attributes.Add("DayNameFormat", "FirstLetter")
    calendar1.Attributes.Add("CellPadding", "4")
    calendar1.Attributes.Add("ShowNextPrevMonth", "True")
    calendar1.Attributes.Add("SelectionMode", "Day")
    calendar1.Attributes.Add("ShowTitle", "false")
    calendar1.Attributes.Add("OnSelectionChanged", "Calendar_SelectionChanged")
    calendar1.TodayDayStyle.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Black
    calendar1.Attributes.Add("todaydaystyle-backcolor", "#cccccc")
    calendar1.Attributes.Add("selectorstyle-backcolor", "#cccccc")
    calendar1.NextPrevStyle.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Bottom
    calendar1.Attributes.Add("dayheaderstyle-font-size", "7pt")
    calendar1.Attributes.Add("dayheaderstyle-font-bold", "true")
    calendar1.Attributes.Add("dayheaderstyle-backcolor", "#cccccc")
    calendar1.Attributes.Add("selecteddaystyle-font-bold", "true")
    calendar1.Attributes.Add("selecteddaystyle-forecolor", "White")
    calendar1.Attributes.Add("selecteddaystyle-backcolor", "#666666")
    calendar1.Attributes.Add("titlestyle-font-bold", "true")
    calendar1.TitleStyle.BorderColor = Drawing.Color.Black
    calendar1.Attributes.Add("titlestyle-backcolor", "#999999")
    calendar1.Attributes.Add("weekenddaystyle-backcolor", "#ffffcc")
    calendar1.OtherMonthDayStyle.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Gray

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it question128_Cal1 or question128_Calendar1 ? Your `function use_calendarDate()` refers to the first. Typo ?

> Interestingly, when I use
>
> `var calendarDate = question128_Calendar1.SelectedDate;`
>
> OR
>
> `var calendarDate = question128_Calendar1.value;`
>
> My alert box tells me undefined.

That's because the client script has no knowledge of what 'question128_Calendar1' is. That is a server-side ID.

Is there a reason why you can't use markup to define the calendar instead that rather large 'BuildCalendar' function? You're making a bit of a maintenance nightmare by doing that, IMO.

Comment: the Comment class is used elsewhere in the program. I don't want a calendar in the markup for every Comment control that is added to my page. The software this involves lets users create online survey and tests for consumers. If they decide to put a ton of comment controls in their test, I don't want to hide or disable the calendar every time it is not needed.

Comment: I earlier used question128_divCal1.style.display to hide or show the div containing the Calendar, dropdown list, etc. on a button click. So I don't see why it wouldn't recognize question128_Cal1 also.

Comment: To anyone who still may read this, I used a completely different way of doing this. With AjaxToolkit's Calendar Extender, I was able to easily add a calendar dynamically and use Javascript to change the format of different date inputs so that calendar extender could read it. Highly recommend you go the AjaxToolkit route if you are trying to do something similar to me.